# Laravel 8 : Storage::delete (file) return false

Tags: laravel, delete-file

Since yesterday I cannot delete a file from the folder
This my code in the controller.
​
public function update_avatar(Request $request)
{

```
    // Handle the user upload of avatar
    if ($request->hasfile('avatar')) {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if (auth()->user()->avatar) {
            // dd('/uploads/avatars/'. auth()->user()->avatar);
            Storage::delete('/uploads/avatars/'. auth()->user()->avatar);
            //dd(Storage::delete('/uploads/avatars/'. auth()->user()->avatar));
        }
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(500, 500)->save(public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename));

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }

    return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );

}
```

​

which does not delete the file in the folder, after debugging the method

​ `dd('/uploads/avatars/'. auth()->user()->avatar); ​`

i get the file correctly, but when I debug on

`dd(Storage::delete('/uploads/avatars/'. auth()->user()->avatar)); ​`

the result is *FALSE*

ps: Im using laravel 8

Comment: can you give example of your complete path where it lies, also can you try `File::delete($filename);` and add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`

Comment: When saving the image, you use the `public_path()` helper. Makes sense that it should be used when deleting a file also, no?

Comment: is the `public` disk your default storage disk?

Comment: @bhucho, thanks for the correction, I used `File :: delete (public_path ('/ uploads / avatars /'. Auth :: user () -> avatar));` and it deletes the file with no problem.

Comment: Now I would like to know what is the difference between
**Storage :: delete** and **File :: delete**, because even in Laravel's documentation and several tutorials we only mention Storage :: delete and almost never File :: delete.

Comment: As stated by @lagbox asking that is your storage disk set to public, you can check it from config/filesystems.php, by default it is set to app storage path, so If you add disk as public the Storage::delete() function would be able to delete it I guess I will explain it in answer column

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first you are doing `Storage::delete('/uploads/avatars/'. auth()->user()->avatar);` so by default if you have not changed anything, the disk is set to local,

You can check it from your `config/filesystems.php`(Showing here from laravel github official repo (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/filesystems.php#L44))

So if you select, `Storage::disk('public')->delete($filename);`, it would select the disk for public with path, app/public, even you can add it manually(I have not tested this method so can't guarantee its success.)

Second, if you use **File**,
As you can see from https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L262,
it basically calls unlink() method of php.
Basically both of them call the delete method in `Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem`, but passing the path & methods of calling are different.

So you can use either,

- use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\File`;  `File::delete($filename);`
- use `IIlluminate\Support\Facades\Storage` `Storage::disk('public')->delete($filename);`  (on [github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Storage.php))
- unlink() from php

Comment: Thank you very much for all the explanation

Answer (score 0):

DO this .

```
       if (Storage::exists('public'.$slider->image)) {
            Storage::delete('public'.$slider->image);
        }
```

Store method

```
        $image = Storage::disk('public')->put('admin/slider/', $request->image);
        $image = basename($image);
        $slider->image = '/admin/slider/' . $image;
```

save image using storage method in Database.
[image]